# Adding Enum to MVC View breaks returned model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(ExempKillData kill)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(kill).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Owners");
            }
            return View(kill);
        }
```

and this (snipped-for-length) model:

```
[Display(Name ="No Data")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string NO_DATA { get; set; }

        public DisposalMethods MethodOfDisposal { get; set; }

        public int ID { get; set; }
```

and this (snipped-for-length) view:

```
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.SPECIES, null, "SPECIES", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.SPECIES, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => kill.MethodOfDisposal, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.EXEM_YEAR, null, "EXEM_YEAR", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.EXEM_YEAR, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
```

I have tried both of these methods for declaring the dropdown:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => kill.MethodOfDisposal, "MethodOfDisposal", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => kill.MethodOfDisposal, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It works perfectly if I comment out the @Html.EnumDropDownListFor -- the model returned to the controller is fully detailed, except for the Enum value.

[image: Good model]

As soon as I uncomment the EnumDropDownList, the model returned to the controller is all null values. ...except the MethodOfDisposal.

[image: Null model]

...this is despite my data looking good coming from the POST action on the view:

[image: Good data]

What am I doing wrong?  I would expect adding a new field to the view to *not* break the rest of the model.

Comment: Have you had a look at the requests being sent to the action (browser dev tools)?  Does the request look ok?  If it does, there may be an exception somewhere being suppressed which might give you an insight into why the model binding is failing (if that is the problem).

Comment: @PhilCooper - the request looks okay when it is sent from the browser, but when it arrives at the controller, it is all nulls.  Any thoughts on where to look for suppressed errors?

Comment: If you open your exception settings (I presume you're using VS), ensure the CLR (Common Language Runtime) exceptions are checked on.  When debugging, this will expose all the exceptions occuring as part of the request handling.  Hopefully you'll see something that might hint towards a binding exception preventing your model from being bound from the request.